# Lazy-loading library?

Tags: java, orm, lazy-loading

Is there a library that deals exclusively with lazy-loading class fields without all the bells and whistles of full-fledged ORM? Alternatively, which ORM (with a liberal license) provides the best lazy-loading mechanism that I can reuse?

Comment: + 1 Good question. If you will find any info yourself. Please don't delete this topic. Instead post information here.

Comment: Can you expand on why you need a minimal lazy-loading ORM?

Comment: I need a lazy-loading library (not ORM) because I plan on using plain JDBC in my application and I don't want a full-fledged ORM. As to the why no ORM: http://blogs.tedneward.com/2006/06/26/The+Vietnam+Of+Computer+Science.aspx

Comment: In terms of a lightweight ORM, you might want to check out ormlite (http://ormlite.com/).  This isn't a solution however because lazy loading is not supported directly -- at least not he way hibernate does with its magic collections.  However there are examples of how to use the package to support many-to-many and other relationships.

Answer (score 1):

[MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/) sounds like it might be just what your after. It's not an ORM, but a "data mapper" to map SQL statements (or stored procedures) to objects. There are both Java and .Net versions.

In my experience, it works very well, and is far simpler to use than a full blown ORM (I'm looking at you Hibernate). The community remains active, and has spawned [a number of integration projects](http://www.mybatis.org/java.html) for libraries like Spring and Guice, as well as MyBatis Migrations for managing databases (similar to RoR Migrations).